# Is it known whether Minimum Cost Multicut is APX-hard?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, approximation-algorithms

My questions is concerned with the following problem: Given an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$ and (edge costs) $c \in \mathbb{Z}^E$,
$$\min \left\{ \sum_{e \in E} c_e x_e\ \middle|\ x \in \{0,1\}^E \ \wedge\ \forall C \in \mathrm{cycles}(G)\ \forall e \in C:\ x_e \leq \!\!\!\!\sum_{e' \in C \setminus \{e\}} \!\! x_{e'}  \right\}$$

This problem, studied by [Chopra and Rao (1993)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01581239), is sometimes called Minimum Cost Multicut, although the term is used also for different problems in the literature (e.g. [this](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node93.html) problem with terminals and positive edge weights).

Is the problem stated above known to be APX-hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is APX-hard. A proof by Demaine et al. is published [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397506003227).